# How to auto-refresh time in React when using 'date-fns' library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I am working on my personal Portfolio using React and I want to add a statement on the landing page that displays my local time and timezone to recruiters, as seen below:
[image: Time]

I have implemented this using the **date-fns** library but I am currently facing one issue. As time goes by, the time values on the screen stay constant and do not update themselves automatically. As we speak, it is currently 16:58 but the time still shows 16:47. I have to do a manual refresh for the updated time values to show. I want to implement this in such a way that the time will update every 60 seconds and show the current time always.

I wrote this Class component to implement the feature:

```
export class Time extends Component {

  constructor() {
  super();
    var today = new Date();

    var time = format(today, 'HH:mm')

    this.state = {

      currentTime: time

    }

  }

   
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="time">
        <p>
          My Local Time is { this.state.currentTime } GMT +3
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

setInterval(Time, 60000);
```

What could I do to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the [solution provided Luke-shang-04](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467370/10871073) but I ran into issues with declaration of the `intervalId` variable. I therefore resorted to using React Hooks and converted this component into a Functional component.

The code below works:

```
export const Time = () => {
   

  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      
        setTime(new Date());
      }, 60000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    } 
  )

  return(
    <div>
      <p>{`My local time is ${format(time, 'HH:mm')} GMT+3`} </p>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `componentDidMount` method, and place the `setInterval` in there. Make sure that the `setInterval` updates `this.state.currentTime`. It's also a good idea to clear the interval afterwards, so store the interval id and then call `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`.

Something like this

```
export class Time extends Component {
    intervalId

    constructor() {
        super()
        var today = new Date()

        var time = format(today, "HH:mm")

        this.state = {
            currentTime: time,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var today = new Date()

        var time = format(today, "HH:mm")

        intervalId = setInterval(() =>
            this.setState({
                currentTime: time,
            }),
            60000
        )
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(intervalId) // Clear interval to prevent memory leaks
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="time">
                <p>My Local Time is {this.state.currentTime} GMT +3</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I would suggest that you read up on the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), since these are the basics of React.